# What is the proper way to package path unit files?

Tags: packaging

I have a lot of application packages that I help maintain. Many of the applications run as systemd services. To install a package as a service it is very easy to place a `service` file in the `debian` directory of the package source. When the package is installed, this `debian/service` file is automatically installed as `/lib/systemd/system/[package-name].service`. This has been working excellently for us for years.

Recently we found the need to start using [path units](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.path.html) alongside the [service units](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) in our packages. It seems like it would be pretty straight forward to just add a file named `path` to the `debian` directory. However, I have built and installed a package several times now and while the `service` unit file gets installed, the `path` unit file does not. I have also tried naming both files with the package name (eg `package.service` and `package.path`) without success, meaning that the `service` file gets installed but the `path` file does not.

What am I doing wrong? How do I properly package the application so that the `path` unit gets installed with the `service` unit?

---

As a workaround, I currently create the `/lib/systemd/system/[package-name].path` path/file in the `debian` directory and add a line to the `install` file to get the file into the proper place:

```
debian/lib/systemd/system/[package-name].path lib/systemd/system/
```

Comment: This bug report seems to indicate that `path unit` support was added: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=768609

Comment: Looks like that bug report shows that it is not yet in stable, so this should probably show up in future versions.